# XCode 6: I can't select a view by its storyboard ID

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, storyboard

This is the code :

```
let theBoard = self.storyboard!
let vc = theBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myViewId")  as! UIViewController // this line causes the error
```

The second line causes this error:

```
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

*** VERY IMPORTANT *** : the error only fires when the build configuration is set to "`debug`". It works well when set to "`release`".

Why ?

Comment: are you sure when u release it show you a destination storyboard?

Comment: absolutely, on release the view displays

Comment: Clean project and rebuild

Comment: Done several times, derivedData also deleted

Comment: Did you verify it's not `theBoard` that is nil?

Answer (score 0):

You are casting UIViewController in the `let vc = theBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myViewId")  as! UIViewController` which is wrong.
You should try:

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

var vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myViewId") as! ViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
var moveToNextVC:ViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myViewId") as! ViewController

 self.presentViewController(moveToNextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Remember set StoryboardID Identify 'myViewId' in File Inspector for your viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

It all is a matter of the new syntax, functionality hasn't changed:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController") as! UIViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but why does it work in release and not in debug ?

Comment: There is probably some configuration somewhere that is wrong. That is what I am looking for.